# How to define macro function with variable name

Tags: c++

I want to define a macro like

```
#define AUTO_FUC(x) void x(){}
```

to define a function named x.

I think the function name will be replaced by x passed by arg x.

```
AUTO_FUC("test")//it should equal to void test(){} I think
```

But it didn't.

So how to do this in C++?

---

I use MinGW and use the macro twice with different args.

```
AUTO_FUC("A")
AUTO_FUC("B")
```

It didn't give me function A() and B().Compiler told me `void someClass::x() cannot be overloaded`.So I know the macro didn't work.

---

Thanks ,I realize the void "A"() is not a correct function. I forgot I pass a macro as arg and the marco is a string.

**And further question**. What I really want is create a function with name according to a variable value.And variable value can be write like `string a = a;`? It should have `"` am I right? So If I use a string like `"A"`, how can I use the `A` to create the function `void A()` when pass the value to marco?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#define AUTO_FUC(x) \
void x() \
{\
    std::cout<<"hi";\
}\

int main()
{
    std::string A = "A";
    AUTO_FUC(A);  //it's equal to AUTO_FUC("A") it wrong
    A(); //So it's undefined;
}
```

Comment: How do you know it didn't work?

Comment: [Post a Minimal, Complete, Valid Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: AUTO_FUC is an interesting name for this macro, what do you want it to do?

Comment: @MattCoubrough I saw something similar on a website the other day at work and then got told off for "browsing for private interests".

Comment: "What I really want..." you can't, but if you explain *why* you want to perhaps we can suggest something.  (To elaborate: AUTO_FUC(A) will generate a function called `A` whether or not `A` happens to be a local `string` variable with whatever value, so `A()` *is* defined but not because the variable `A` had value `"A"` - you should get more creative with your values so it's less confusing! ;-P)

Comment: @TonyD I just try to find is there any convenient way to write beautiful code. Thanks ! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're not passing in `A` and `B` (identifiers). You're passing in `"A"` and `"B"` (string literals). Macros are *textual* replacement. So they expand to:

```
void "A"(){}
void "B"(){}
```

Surely you'll agree that's not correct C++ code. Change it to this:

```
AUTO_FUC(A)
AUTO_FUC(B)
```

Answer (score 2):

[ UPDATE: you've edited your question and now show code where the macro parameters are quoted.  Next time, try to post your actual code when asking the question! ;-P ]

Your code works just fine... see it running at ideone.com [here](http://ideone.com/r73tX6)

```
#include <iostream>

#define AUTO_FUC(x) void x(){ std::cout << "hi!\n"; }
AUTO_FUC(test)

int main()
{
    test();
}
```

stdout

```
hi!
```